# Pythonでデスクトップに画像のみを表示する方法を教えてください。

Tags: python, 画像

Pythonでの画像表示について質問です。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

この画像のような透過PNGの画像をデスクトップ上に、ウィンドウなしに、HUDのように表示させるには、どのようにすれば、よいでしょうか？

完成イメージとしてはこのようなものです。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

なお環境はmacOS Sierra、Python 3.6.1 (Anaconda)です。
外部のライブラリなどでも構いません。

Comment: クロスプラットフォームのGUIライブラリもありますが、一応想定している動作環境（OS）を示して置くとよいと思います。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。動作環境を追加しておきます

Comment: Dashboard Widgetで作ればHTMLだけでできそうです...。